# oracle result set in html similar to SQL*Plus (using SQL only)

Tags: html, sql, oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus

To give an example straightaway, below is what I would like to do (without using SQL*Plus):
In SQL*Plus:

```
SQL> set feed off markup html on
SQL> select * from emp where rownum<=2;
```

gives this output:

```
<p>
<table border="1" width="90%" summary="Script output">
<tr>
<th scope="col">
EMPNO
</th>
<th scope="col">
ENAME
</th>
<th scope="col">
JOB
</th>
<th scope="col">
MGR
</th>
<th scope="col">
HIREDATE
</th>
<th scope="col">
SAL
</th>
<th scope="col">
COMM
</th>
<th scope="col">
DEPTNO
</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">
      7369
</td>
<td>
SMITH
</td>
<td>
CLERK
</td>
<td align="right">
      7902
</td>
<td>
17-DEC-80
</td>
<td align="right">
       800
</td>
<td align="right">
&nbsp;
</td>
<td align="right">
        20
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">
      7499
</td>
<td>
ALLEN
</td>
<td>
SALESMAN
</td>
<td align="right">
      7698
</td>
<td>
20-FEB-81
</td>
<td align="right">
      1600
</td>
<td align="right">
       300
</td>
<td align="right">
        30
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<p>
```

Is there a straightforward way to do this in SQL only? (using one or more Oracle's XML functions, for example). Any pointers would be most welcome.

EDIT:
To clarify a bit more, I do NOT care for the whitespace or the `p` / `table` tags and the attributes of each tags, just the structured html.

Comment: can you use PLSQL for this?

Comment: You can try and wrap this using the packages such as UTL_FILE and write to files. You would still need some kind of stored procedure that would be executed from your non-SQLPLUS client.

Comment: Just concatenate all the html tags in your select statement.  It will be long and ugly, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0de44d/5)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE EMP ( EMPNO, ENAME, JOB, MGR, HIREDATE, SAL, COMM, DEPTNO ) AS
SELECT 7369, 'Smith', 'Clerk', 7902, DATE '1980-12-17', 800, CAST( NULL AS NUMBER(5,2) ), 20 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7499, 'Allen', 'Salesman', 7698, DATE '1981-02-20', 1600, 300, 30 FROM DUAL
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT XMLElement(
         "p",
         XMLElement(
           "table",
           XMLElement( "tr",
             XMLForest(
               'empno'    AS "th",
               'ename'    AS "th",
               'job'      AS "th",
               'mgr'      AS "th",
               'hiredate' AS "th",
               'sal'      AS "th",
               'comm'     AS "th",
               'deptno'   AS "th"
             )
           ),
           XMLAgg(
             XMLElement( "tr",
               XMLForest(
                 empno    AS "td",
                 ename    AS "td",
                 job      AS "td",
                 mgr      AS "td",
                 hiredate AS "td",
                 sal      AS "td",
                 comm     AS "td",
                 deptno   AS "td"
               )
             )
           )
         )
       ).getClobVal() AS XML
FROM   EMP
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0de44d/5/0)**:

```
|                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            XML |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| <p><table><tr><th>empno</th><th>ename</th><th>job</th><th>mgr</th><th>hiredate</th><th>sal</th><th>comm</th><th>deptno</th></tr><tr><td>7369</td><td>Smith</td><td>Clerk</td><td>7902</td><td>1980-12-17</td><td>800</td><td>20</td></tr><tr><td>7499</td><td>Allen</td><td>Salesman</td><td>7698</td><td>1981-02-20</td><td>1600</td><td>300</td><td>30</td></tr></table></p> |
```

Comment: You nailed it. Thank you.